# Using python dict imported from file in another python file

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4

I've the same issue as asked by the OP in [How to import or include data structures (e.g. a dict) into a Python file from a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132985/how-to-import-or-include-data-structures-e-g-a-dict-into-a-python-file-from-a). However for some reason i'm unable to get it working.

My setup is as follows:

file1.py:

```
TMP_DATA_FILE = {'a':'val1', 'b':'val2'}
```

file2.py:

```
from file1 import TMP_DATA_FILE

var = 'a'
print(TMP_DATA_FILE[var])
```

When i do this and run the script from cmd line, it says string indices must be integers.

When i do `type(TMP_DATA_FILE)`, i get class 'str'. I tried to convert this to dict to be able to use dict operations, but couldn't get it working.

If i do `print(TMP_DATA_FILE.get(var))`, since i'm developing using PyCharm, it lists dict operations like get(), keys(), items(), fromkeys() etc, however when i run the program from command line it says 'str' object has no attributes 'get'.

When i do `print(TMP_DATA_FILE)` it just lists 'val1'. It doesn't list 'a', 'b', 'val2'.

However the same script when run from PyCharm works without any issues. It's just when i run the script from command line as a separate interpreter process it gives those errors.

I'm not sure if it's PyCharm that's causing the errors or if i'm doing anything wrong.

Originally i had only one key:value in the dict variable and it worked, when i added new key:value pair that's when it started giving those errors.

I've also tried using `ast.literal_eval` & `eval`, neither of them worked. Not sure where i'm going wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention - file1.py & file2.py are in different folders and i do have `__init__.py` in both folders. I also tried json options reading from some of the posts, those didn't work either.

Comment: I've edited my question to change the import statement. This is the current style of import that i've which i forgot to mention while asking the question. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: check my answer once, may be it helps

Comment: Thanks mescalinum for the tip. That was indeed the problem. I didn't had the right folders in PYTHONPATH. It works now. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways you can access variable `TMP_DATA_FILE` in file `file1.py`:

```
import file1
var = 'a'
print(file1.TMP_DATA_FILE[var])
```

or:

```
from file1 import TMP_DATA_FILE
var = 'a'
print(TMP_DATA_FILE[var])
```

`file1.py` is in a directory contained in the python search path, or in the same directory as the file importing it.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source#answer-3144107) about the python search path.

Comment: They could be in subdirectories not a same directory, I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `package`s created in your project, then you have to link the file from the main project.

For example:
If you have a folder `Z` which contains 2 folders `A` and `B` and those 2 files `file1.py` and `file2.py` are present in `A` and `B` folders, then you have to import it this way

```
import Z.A.file1
print(file1.TMP_DATA_FILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You calling it the wrong way. It should be like this :

```
print file1.TMP_DATA_FILE[var]
```

Comment: I've tried this approach as well and this was my original code. It didn't work. I should've amended the question to reflect the latest code where i'm doing `from file1 import dictVariable`, and that's why i've `dictVariable[var]`

Answer (score 1):

Correct variant:

```
import file1    
var = 'a'
print(file1.TMP_DATA_FILE[var])
```

or

```
from file1 import TMP_DATA_FILE
var = 'a'
print(TMP_DATA_FILE[var])
```